# docker compose image no longer working laravel

Tags: laravel, docker-compose

I have a laravel app that I develop locally using docker to create the containers.

This has worked for months, I haven't developed the app for the past 2 months but today when I start the containers I can no longer communicate from the php instance to the database instance.  I can connect to the server using my localhost address on the machine but when I try and do anything on the php container (e.g. user logs in to the app) it comes up with connection refused.

So to  summarise, I can do php artisan migrate from my laptop and tables get created, I then view the site (localhost:8080) and the login screen shows, I then try and login and get the below error:

> Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (2002) SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]
>   Connection refused (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` =
>   test@email.com and `users`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1)

I have included all my files below

`.env`

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=**REMOVED**
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=https://localhost:8443
APP_CDN=true

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=33061
DB_DATABASE=dockerApp
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2'

services:
    nginx:
      image: nginx:1.13.12
      ports:
        - "8443:443"
        - "8080:80"
      volumes:
        - ./:/var/www
        - ./nginxconf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
        - ./ssl-cert:/etc/nginx/certs
      working_dir: /var/www
      links:
        - php
    php:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: app.docker
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
        links:
            - db
        environment:
            - "DB_PORT=3306"
            - "DB_HOST=db"
    db:
        image: mysql:5.7
        environment:
            - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret"
            - "MYSQL_DATABASE=dockerApp"
        ports:
            - "33061:3306"
```

`app.docker`

```
FROM php:7-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev mysql-client \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
    && pecl install mcrypt-1.0.1 docker-php-ext-enable mcrypt

WORKDIR /var/www
```

`vhost.conf`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
    }
    location ~\.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443;
    ssl on;
    root /var/www/public;

    ssl_certificate     /var/www/ssl-cert/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/www/ssl-cert/server.key;
    ssl_password_file   /var/www/ssl-cert/passwords.txt;
    ssl_client_certificate /var/www/ssl-cert/ca.crt;
    ssl_verify_client on;
}
```

Comment: docker creates its own internal network that you can try and use to connect to the DB image. Change your `.env` file values `DB_HOST=db`, `DB_PORT=3306`

Comment: @AngadDubey when I do that it works for logging in but I can then no longer connect to it locally so I'm unable to do any migrations etc

Comment: you should be running your migrations within the docker container - docker-compose run <container name> php artisan migrate

Comment: @AngadDubey I have always ran them locally and it has always worked until recently